# Dropdown menu content overlaps its menu item

Tags: html, css

When displaying navigation bar at left and right, dropdown always displays at last, it should come in between other links and dropdown content overlapping dropdown button.

Dropdown content overlaps dropdown. How to correct it?

```css
body {
  color: #959595;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-left {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 14px;
}

.navbar-Logo {
  float: right;
  color: #dd845a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-Logo a {
  float: right;
  color: #dd845a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-Logo:hover,
.navbar-Logo:focus {
  color: sienna;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-right {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.nav-right a {
  display: inline;
  color: black;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  padding-left: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.rightbar_items {
  float: left;
  color: #dd845a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#rb {
  float: right;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: inherit;
  /*font-family: inherit;*/
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.nav-right a:hover {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Navigation -->
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="nav-left">
    <a class="navbar-Logo" href="#">LOGO</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-right">
    <div id="rb">
      <a class="rightbar_items" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="rightbar_items" href="#">Products</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Services 
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">abc</a>
          <a href="#">def</a>
          <a href="#">ghi</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="rightbar_items" href="#">My Account</a>
      <a class="rightbar_items" href="#">My Cart</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try add `position: relative;` to `.dropdown` and `top: 100%` to `.dropdown-content`.

Comment: I would start by getting rid of those floats. There are much better techniques for alignment to be found.

Comment: @isherwood- I am new to HTML and CSS, please suggest any other alignment techniques other than float

Answer (score -1):

Add `top: 40px;` to `.dropdown-content` and take out all the floats except the one in `.nav-right`.

```css
body {
  color: #959595;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-left {
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 14px;
}

.navbar-Logo {
  color: #dd845a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-Logo a {
  color: #dd845a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-Logo:hover,
.navbar-Logo:focus {
  color: sienna;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-right {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.nav-right a {
  display: inline;
  color: black;
  /*text-align: center;*/
  padding-left: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.rightbar_items {
  color: #dd845a;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#rb {
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: inherit;
  /*font-family: inherit;*/
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-right a:hover {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 80px;
  /* added top: 40px */
  top: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Navigation -->
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="nav-left">
    <a class="navbar-Logo" href="#">LOGO</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-right">
    <div id="rb">
      <a class="rightbar_items" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="rightbar_items" href="#">Products</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Services 
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">abc</a>
          <a href="#">def</a>
          <a href="#">ghi</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="rightbar_items" href="#">My Account</a>
      <a class="rightbar_items" href="#">My Cart</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```